# Send msg from ubuntu server to windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7

Is there any way to send a msg (something like NET SEND or MSG.exe) from ubuntu server 11.04 64bit to windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this in ages (at least 10 years), but `smbclient` from the package with the same name used to be able to send SMB messages.

Comment: Isn't the messenger service disabled in most modern windows installations?